# Optimize Adding Hyperlinks Syntax

Tags: c#, excel, performance, c#-4.0, hyperlink

I have a worksheet, where I am adding 500 hyperlinks, and this process takes roughly 90 seconds to complete.  I know partly this is due to being forced to use the Microsoft Interop Excel, and partly from being forced to use a `for loop`, but there has to be a faster/more efficient way of achieving such.  This is my current syntax

```
public static void AddThatHyper()
{
    long lr, i;
    string cellVal;
    WS = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    lr = WS.Cells[WS.Rows.Count, 2].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
    for (i = 2; i <= lr; i++)
    {
        Object Anchor = WS.Cells[i, 9];
        Object TextToDisplay = Convert.ToString(WS.Cells[i, 9]);
        cellVal = WS.Cells[i, 1].Value;
        cellVal = cellVal.Substring(0, Math.Min(28, cellVal.Length));
        rangeToHoldHyperlink = WS.Range["I" + i];

        if (cellVal.Contains("&") ||
            cellVal.Contains(",") ||
            cellVal.Contains("-") ||
            cellVal.Contains(".")
           )
        {
            xlApp.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, "", "'" + "CR " + cellVal + "'!A1", "", TextToDisplay);
        }
        if (cellVal.Contains("'"))
        {
            cellVal = cellVal.Replace("'", "''");
            xlApp.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, "", "'" + "CR " + cellVal + "'!A1", "", TextToDisplay);
        }
        else
        {
            xlApp.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor, "", "'" + "FR " + cellVal + "'!A1", "", TextToDisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

What can be done here to optimize this syntax and have it complete in a faster time frame?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to read and write to cells individually. The best way to reduce execution time is reading all the values as a range and storing these in an array. After which you manipulate this and then set the values for the entire range. Thus reducing the amount of COM calls you're program has to make. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846958/optimized-way-of-adding-multiple-hyperlinks-in-excel-file-with-c-sharp?rq=1.

Comment: @Seunhaab - that option may work, but it I am unclear on how to achieve such.  Can you provide sample syntax?  The URL set-up on those answers is different than mine as I have 3 possible conditions on how the URL should be.

Answer (score 0):

Note, this code was not tested. It's an example based on a program I have made before. You might have to do some manual debugging to see if values are being extracted/converted properly.

```
public static void AddThatHyper()
{
    long lr, i;
    string cellVal;
    WS = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    lr = WS.Cells[WS.Rows.Count, 2].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
    string prefix = "";      

    string topCell = "I" + 2;
    string bottomCell = "I" + lr;

    //get_Range returns object array
    Range range = ws.get_Range(topCell, bottomCell);

    object[,] rangeValues = new object[lr - 2, 1];
    string[,] rangeStringValues = new string[lr - 2, 1];
    rangeValues = range.Cells.Formula;

    //turn object array into string array
    //should contain strings like "=hyperlink(url, text)"
    for (int i = 0; i < rangeValues.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        rangeStringValues[i, 0] = rangeValues[i, 0]?.ToString() ?? "";
    }

    //edit hyperlinks
    for (int i = 0; i < rangeStringValues.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        prefix = "FR"
        string hyperlink = rangeStringValues[i, 0];
        MatchCollection fields =  Regex.Matches(hyperlink, @"("[A-Za-z0-9\.]*")");
        string url = fields[0]?.ToString() ?? "";
        string text = fields[1]?.ToString() ?? "";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(url, @"[&,\-\.]"))
            prefix = "CR";
        else if (url.Contains("'"))
        {
            prefix = "CR"
            url.Replace("'", "''");
        }
        string formattedUrl = "'" + prefix + url + "'!A1";
        rangeStringValues[i, 0]= $"=HYPERLINK(""{formattedUrl }"", ""{text}"")";

    }
    range.set_Value(value: values);
    range.Formula = range.Value;
}
```